# Tabela Recebe 2 chaves estrageiras - Modelo Relacional

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Tenho uma tabela que se chama QR-Code, este pode ser enviado tal por um funcionario, ou por um residente, mas na tabela Qr-code tem que ter somente um codigo de quem um enviou, como consigo representar isso no modelo relacional??

---

De momentos não estou perto de um conputador então essa demonstração não ta la grande coisa, é o seguinte o Qr-code só ira receber um codigo , ou de funcionario ou de residente, mas o problema é que ambos tem cardinalidade 1:n
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pesquise por particionamento de entidades. Basicamente você terá um remetente que poderá ser um funcionário ou um residente.

Comment: Alvino, sugiro que faça o DDL inicial do seu modelo mesmo que sem relacionamentos, colocando as tabelas iniciais e colunas principais. Assim irá trazer mais contexto para a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Criando uma ótica meio genérica da modelagem eu imaginaria algo assim:

- Guarda todo o pessoal
  Pessoas(ID, Nome);
- Classifica funcionários
  Funcionarios(Pessoa_ID, Matricula, [...]);
- Classifica residentes
  Residentes(Pessoa_ID, Registro, [...]);
- Dados qr.
  QR_Code(ID, ID_Pessoa, [...]);

Depois é só fazer uma junção chamando uma ou as duas tabelas.

```
SELECT
   P.ID,
   P.Nome,
   ISNULL(F.Matricula, '-') AS Matricula,
   ISNULL(R.Pessoa_ID, '-') AS Registro 
FROM Pessoas P
INNER JOIN Funcionarios F
ON F.Pessoa_ID = P.ID
INNER JOIN Residentes R 
ON R.Pessoa_ID = P.ID
```

Comment: Obrigado , ja entendi o que tenho que fazer. Vlw

Answer (score 0):

O melhor que tem a fazer é criar uma tabela que é a tabela pai de `residente` e de `funcionário`, então a tabela `Qr-code` apenas tem uma relação com essa tabela pai.

Tem de ver se existem colunas em comum entre `residente` e `funcionário` e colocar essas colunas comuns na tabela pai.

Nas tabelas `residente` e `funcionário` tem uma `FK` para a tabela pai.

desta forma consegue ter uma relação de `1:N` entre a relação pai e a tabela `Qr-code`, sendo que esta tabela pai representa ou um `residente` ou um `funcionário`.

Comment: Então as chaves de funcionários e residentes seriam uma chave primária e estrangeira ao mesmo tempo, não??

Comment: Claro que sim, as chaves estrangeiras costumam ser chaves primárias.